# Do Traditionalists still exist?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-religion

I was wondering if the philosophy of Traditionalism (a la Rene Guenon and followers) still had followers and thinkers writing? If so, who?

Comment: Welcome! Any chance I could persuade you to give a little more context here -- perhaps tell us a little bit more about the problem you are working on, maybe expand on what you have already found out so far? Just in passing, the headline might perhaps be more constructively-posed as 'which if any are the most significant living/still-writing students of Guenon?' rather than the somewhat unclear 'do traditionalists still exist?'

Answer (score 2):

It would seem they must; there is still a functioning [Traditionalist publishing house](http://www.sophiaperennis.com/), which is [active on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/sperennispress) and has more than 500 "friends", so it would definitely appear that there are new publications and active readers.